# calling a jquery function through button_to in ruby on rails

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

Below is the code of a button i n ruby on rails

```
<%= button_to "btnAdd"%>
```

and below is the jquery function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#btnAdd").click(function() {
              alert("Hassan")
        });
</script>
```

I want to call jquery function through button. But its not going into the jquery function, why. Kindly reply me. Thanks

Comment: can you share the generated html

Comment: I have added my answer.Check it.

Answer (score 1):

[`button_to`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-button_to) generates a form with a input type="submit" button like:

```
<%= button_to "btnAdd"%>
# => "<form method="post" action="" class="button_to">
#      <div><input value="btnAdd" type="submit" /></div>
#    </form>"
```

So try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("input[value='btnAdd']").click(function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      alert("Hassan");
    }
});
```

<kbd>[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/wF6TL/)</kbd>

Comment: @HassanAliKhan, this answer is succinct and effective. You should accept it as correct.

Comment: What is the error in rails console/browser console?

Comment: @HassanAliKhan, care to enlighten as to what _exactly_ is the problem? As far as I can see, this solution should work flawlessly.

Comment: @zeantsoi I think the id is not set.see my answer.

Comment: @Pavan, the `id` attribute has __nothing__ to do with whether or not the HTML element can be detect from within the DOM. `$("input[value='btnAdd']")` selects the DOM element more elegantly – and with less markup – than your solution does.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you haven't set an `id` for your button.Try this:

```
<div id="btn">
  <%= button_to "btnAdd" %>
</div>

#=> <input type="submit" value="btnAdd" id="btn" />
```

Change your Jquery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#btn").click(function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();
      alert("Hassan");
    });
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Pavan28/3zJBH/8/)